# Java code for getting current time

Tags: java, time

I am searching code in `java` for fetching or synchronizing my local PC system time into my application.

Answer (score 167):

Try this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class currentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
    }

}
```

You can format SimpleDateFormat in the way you like. For any additional information you can look in java api:

[SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: no need to call the cal.getTime() method 2 time, it could have been assigned to string after formatting the date like this .......SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");String loginTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

Comment: FYI, the troublesome classes used here are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: For the lazy (oneliner, no imports, just copy-paste it): `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime())`

Answer (score 151):

Both

`new java.util.Date()`

and

`System.currentTimeMillis()`

will give you current system time.

Answer (score 51):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()  // UTC
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now(
    // Specify time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
)
```

## Details

The bundled `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar` classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. They are now legacy, supplanted by the [**java.time**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

Instead, use either:

- [**java.time**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)
  Built-in with Java 8 and later. Official successor to Joda-Time.
  Back-ported [to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).
- [**Joda-Time**](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
  Third-party library, open-source, free-of-cost.

## java.time

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

If needed for old code, convert to java.util.Date. Go through at [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

### Time Zone

Better to specify explicitly your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s [current default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );  // Pass desired/expected time zone.
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## Joda-Time

FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
```

To convert from a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object to a java.util.Date for inter-operating with other classes…

```
java.util.Date date = now.toDate();
```

---

Search StackOverflow before posting. Your question has already been asked and answered.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Was his question also answered many times before 7 May '09?

Comment: @skiwi (a) Actually, yes. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java). [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/74620/642706). (b) However, I did fail to notice the age of the question.

Answer (score 10):

System.currentTimeMillis()

everything else works off that.. eg new Date() calls System.currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score 9):

Try this way, more efficient and **compatible**:

```
SimpleDateFormat time_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String current_time_str = time_formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
//Log.i("test", "current_time_str:" + current_time_str);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to inform for furthers developers, and thankfully to Basil Bourque, I just wanna add my stone to this topic.

If you want simply get the HH:MM:SS format then do this:

```
LocalTime hour = ZonedDateTime.now().toLocalTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

Cheers.

P.S.: This will work only at least with Java 8 !

Answer (score 5):

Like said above you can use

```
Date d = new Date();
```

or use

```
Calendar.getInstance();
```

or if you want it in millis

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure about what you meant, but you probably just need

```
Date d = new Date();
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
final String currentTime    = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use new Date () and it'll give you current time.

If you need to represent it in some format (and usually you need to do it) then use formatters.

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance (DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale ("en", "EN"));
String formattedDate = df.format (new Date ());
```

Answer (score 3):

new Date().getTime() is **bugged**.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
    long t1 = date.getTime();
    System.out.println((t1 / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 + ":" + (t1 / 1000 / 60) % 60 + ":" + (t1 / 1000) % 60);
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println((t2 / 1000 / 60 / 60) % 24 + ":" + (t2 / 1000 / 60) % 60 + ":" + (t2 / 1000) % 60);
```

It returns me the wrong time millis. `System.currentTimeMillis()` too. Since I ask the Date **instance** to tell me the corresponding time millis it must return the matching ones not others from a different time zone. Funny how deprecated methods are the only ones which return correct values.

Comment: I am very, very sceptical of your claims of bugs. Unless your system clock has been set incorrectly, of course.

Answer (score 2):

To get system time use Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

And you should get the new instance of Calendar each time to have *current* time.

To *change* system time from java code you can use a command line

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is quite an old question. But would like to clarify that:

```
Date d = new Date()
```

is depriciated in the current versions of Java. The recommended way is using a calendar object. For eg:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentTime = cal.getTime();
```

I hope this will help people who may refer this question in future. Thank you all.

Comment: The top-voted answer already has the Calendar version. What exactly does your post add?

Comment: Yes. But all other answwers speak about the depriciated constructor. Just added a clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Incorrect: The [`Date()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--) constructor is *not* deprecated (as of Java 8). Other methods on that class are deprecated, but not that one. Practically speaking, you should consider it deprecated and instead be using either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get the current date.You can also get current hour, minutes and seconds by using getters :

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).get....()
```