# How to display the time on the right footer when inserting a card?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I'm using GDK `TimelineManager` to insert a static card to the timeline, and I noticed that there's no `just now` or something like that displayed on the right footer.

What am I doing wrong? Is the time just for the Mirror API or am I missing something here?

Comment: are you looking for just static time or referring to a dynamic time option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as of XE12. The APIs you would need are not provided by GDK's static card API.

If this is something you'd like to see in a future release, request it in the [Glass platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)

Answer (score -1):

if you already have a card setup and are looking for static time use java standard libraries to produce a time.

More on this here

[Java code for getting current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833768/java-code-for-getting-current-time)

```
//card 
String time = new java.util.Date();
card1.setText("This card has a footer.");
card1.setFootnote(time);
```

Comment: No I do not want the Footnote to display a static time there, I want the card to display something like "just now" or "2 hours ago" or "yesterday", just as after you take a picture the card displayed on the timeline.

Comment: My mistake I see what you mean, case examples would be a tweet in the mirror api where it shows relative time. 

My guess would be it uses timeline manager to run a background service to get the cards existing with that glassware and using the timeline manager to update it. Theres a stored reference to the time. 

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager

Answer (score -1):

With GDK API it is not possible.

However assuming that this is a view, not the card and if purpose pays the price the classic Android approach can be used. You can create a regular android view and put time wherever you like, just make sure it's right size, the size of the card. There is a way to have overlay view and put time on it in desired coords.

If the point is to have this as a card - then I am out of ideas.