# How to trigger a second event handler after a delay

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

I'm trying to make a 'delete' button that deletes either a) a single character in a text-area if pressed and released in quick succession, or b) all of the text if pressed and held down for more than 2 seconds without release.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some code and show us what have you tried.

Comment: On buttonDown, delete the character and start a 2-second Swing timer; On buttonUp, kill the timer. If the timer ever calls the registered ActionListener (it is invoked before the buttonUp kills it), delete the rest of the text..

Comment: As @msanford suggested, this question is in need of serious improvement. I did what I could with the title/contents, but it's up to you to comply with the guidelines. Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for instance.

Comment: @FredK Seems like a solid answer to me. Would you mind expanding on it and posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to detect long key presses from the keyboard input, you need to understand and use 2 concepts:
1. [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html).
2. How to get [current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833768/java-code-for-getting-current-time).
Once you understand both, just compare the times between keyPressed and keyReleased and call the proper delete action.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly to a Swing-`Timer` (watch [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for example) you could use a simple `SwingWorker` to realize the delay. In general you should not execute a delay, i.e. by `Thread.sleep(1000)`, on the Swing EDT, since this would block the gui ([for further information ...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)). Furthermore you should use a `MouseListener` to capture other informations that you need (stop the timer when mouse is released or exits the buttona area). Here is a very short example:

```
public class JButtonTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButtonTest x = new JButtonTest();
        JButton button = new JButton("Delete");
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            private static final long DELTA = 2000;
            private SwingWorker<Void, Void> waitingWorker;
            private Long timer;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("delete single char");//DO single delete here
                if (waitingWorker != null && !waitingWorker.isDone())
                    waitingWorker.cancel(true);
                waitingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        Thread.sleep(DELTA);
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        if (timer != null && System.currentTimeMillis() >= timer + DELTA)
                            System.out.println("delete all text");//DO text delete here
                    }
                };
                waitingWorker.execute();
            }  
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                timer = null;
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                timer = null;
            }
        });

        x.add(button);
        x.setSize(100, 100);
        x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        x.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I already have something like that but the deletion should happen without the release of the mouse button